# Can I Instantiate a Swift Custom UIView from Storyboard Without It Nesting Inside Itself?

Tags: swift, uiview

Every where I look for how to make a custom UI View with a nib I see the following code to use

```
class CustomView: UIView {


    var contentView: UIView!;

    @IBOutlet weak var sampleLabel: UILabel!

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        if self.subviews.count == 0 {
            nibSetup()
        }

    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        if self.subviews.count == 0 {
            nibSetup()
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        if self.subviews.count == 0 {
            nibSetup()
        }

    }


    fileprivate func nibSetup() {
        contentView = loadViewFromNib()
        contentView.frame = bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        addSubview(contentView)
    }

    fileprivate func loadViewFromNib() -> TimerView {

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
        let nibView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView

        return nibView
    }
}
```

But this basically loads a new instance of the custom view (Loaded from the nib) into a contentView on the original instance. This works until you want to call methods on your view from the view controller it is in. When you want to call a method on the instance from the view controller you are calling it on the original instance not the instance that is in cotnentView so the result is nothing happens.

As a work around I have declared the contentView to be a CustomView instead of a UIView and then my public methods call methods on the content view

ie

```
class CustomView: UIView {


    var contentView: CustomView!;

    @IBOutlet weak var sampleLabel: UILabel!

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        if self.subviews.count == 0 {
            nibSetup()
        }

    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        if self.subviews.count == 0 {
            nibSetup()
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        if self.subviews.count == 0 {
            nibSetup()
        }

    }


    fileprivate func nibSetup() {
        contentView = loadViewFromNib()
        contentView.frame = bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        addSubview(contentView)
    }

    fileprivate func loadViewFromNib() -> TimerView {

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
        let nibView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! CustomView

        return nibView
    }

    func setLabelText(blah: String) {
        sampleLabel.text = blah
    }

    public func setLabelTextFromParent(words: String) {
        contentView.setLabelText(blah: words)
    }
}
```

This seems really hacky though. There has to be a much better way of doing this!

Can someone explain to me how to do this so that I only have one instance of my custom view rather than one nested in another when instantiating it from IB. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an extension on UIView like

```
extension UIView {
    class func fromNib<T : UIView>() -> T {
        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: T.self), owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! T
    }
}
```

I don't see any hack here. 
Call it like

```
let myCustomView: MyCustomView = UIView.fromNib()
```

Comment: How do I use it in a storyboard?

Comment: Its even easier. Drag and drop a normal view on view where you want to place the custom view and change its class to MyCustomView.